# How to get int from string involving other characters?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm writing a program where I want to iterate certain attributes inside a document with an ID that looks like this:

```
"id": "competitor:2672"
```

I want to iterate based on data that I read from an excel file. The only problem is that, in said excel file, the ID is only given as

```
2672
```

in the column "Competitor ID".

I cannot parse the given String to integer. What is the best and cleanest way to compare the two IDs

Using apache POI I want to do something like this

```
String COLUMN_ID = "G" // Column letter in which the IDs are stored
Document home = competitors.get(0);
Document away = competitors.get(1);
String homeIDString = home.get("id").toString();
int homeID = //how to get this from the upper string?
String awayIDString = away.get("id").toString();
int awayID = //how to get this from the upper string?
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
for (int row=0; <something>; row++) {
    XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(COLUMN_ID));
    if (cell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(NUMERIC)) int cellValue = (int) cell.getNumericValue();
    if (cellValue == homeID) { do something }
    else if (cellValue == awayID) { do something }
}
```

Comment: "*I cannot parse the given String to integer.*" -- Why not?  I suppose you could just check to see if the id string ends with the number from excel, but I don't understand what is stopping you from pulling the number out of the string and comparing it as a number.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in programming, but as far as my experience goes, this would give me a **NumberFormatException**. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently getting a `NumberFormatException` because you are trying to convert your `String` into an `int` before comparing it with another `int`.

What @azurefrog is saying is that you can try instead to convert your `int` into a `String` (the other way around) and it will be fine.

`strVariable.endsWith(String.valueOf(intVariable))`

However this has the problem that `"id": "competitor:2672"` and `72` would return `true` too.

---

A better way is to just remove `competitor:` using substring before converting `2672` to an int

```
String myInput = "competitor:2672";      // "competitor:2672"
myInput = myInput.substring(11);         // "2672"
int myValue = Integer.parseInt(myInput); // 2672
```